# How to move block HTML in other block Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have `div` block at page:

```
<div class="item" ng-click="block('block')"></div>
```

After click `block();` I need move this block in another(inside) block:

```
<div class="blocked">insert here</div>
```

And change function param name to `unblock` instead current `block`.
I can give code in Jquery, but how to do it easy in Angular JS?

Comment: I need move block in other block: what does that mean? What is block? What do you mean by "another block"?

Comment: Edited question, sorry, You are right

Comment: Yo dawg I herd you like blocks, so we put a block inside your block so you can block while you block (sorry :-P)

Comment: Could you explain functionally what you are trying to achieve? Without technical details. What are you trying to build? Perhaps make a working sample with jQuery in jsFiddle (or on stackoverlfow, they seem to have runnable code windows these days)

Comment: It's still extremely unclear. Use proper terminology. Something like "When I click this div with class 'item', I want its content to disappear from the div and reappear in the other div with class 'blocked'. And when I click it again, I want the content of the div with class 'blocked' to move back to the div with class 'item'.

Comment: The block wording you are using is really confusing: Block, blocked, unblock. 'Move in another (inside) block', it is not clear at all. It should be as clear as possible. Instead, you could say something like 'I want to move this `.bigBox` div into `.smallBox` div or something.

Comment: I have contact list(two blocks). Active/Blocked. I need click any active contact and ban it. This item must be move to blocked contacts. Your assumptions are correct

Comment: Is block string 'block'? or function name called block? or variable name?

Comment: `Block` is name of function, also block` is string variable - param of function `Block('block')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. So if I understand correctly, your page has two sections. One section lists the active contacts, and the other lists the blocked contacts.

And you want, by clicking on a contact from the "active contacts" section, to move it to the "blocked contacts" section, and vice versa.

The solution is trivial:
The "active contacts" section should filter the contact list and only accept the active ones:

```
ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:isActive"
```

The "blocked contacts" section should filter the contact list and only accept the blocked ones:

```
ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:isBlocked"
```

And the button on the contact should toggle the value of the `active`flag of the contact:

```
ng-click="contact.active = !contact.active"
```

Here is a plnkr demonstrating this: http://plnkr.co/edit/qpGPPS?p=preview

Comment: Need to try, `isActive` is function?

Comment: I think after click I need add  contact to `contacts.bloked` only for `ng-repeat`. How to copy item from `obj1` to `obj2`?

Comment: `obj1.active = {id:1, name:1} to  obj2.blocked = {id:2, name :2}` and get: `obj2.blocked = {id:1, name:1, id:2, name :2}` How do you think?

Comment: Can you explain more please

Comment: A contact has a flag active, which is true or false (false meaning that the contact is blocked). isActive and isBlocked are functions on the scope which take a contact as argument and return true if the conteact is active or blocked respectively.

Comment: Can I see function `isActive`?

Comment: `$scope.isActive = function(contact) { return contact.active; }; $scope.isBlocked = function(contact) { return !contact.active; };`

Comment: A little problem. I have array `friendList`: `[{"name":"Dana","photo":"http://whost.com/public/images/nonphoto_user.png","id":"534","unread":null,"online":0,"blocked":true}]` for `ng-repeat: ng-repeat="friend in friendList | filter:{blocked:'true'}"` So this note does not appear in `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="item" ng-click="block(block)" ng-hide="block"></div>
<div class="blocked"><div class="item" ng-click="block(unblock)" ng-show="block"></div></div>
```

js

```
$scope.block = function(block){
$scope.block = true;
}
```

Comment: This example will show only one block by click, but not move block